# Problems implementing Google Maps API (for Business)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This should be pretty basic but I cant really find the answer to it:

I try to implement a Google map, using the Google API for business and got a working client ID / key.

Using the standard examples from for the documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) its only possible to get a blank map.

This is the simple test code that show a blank map:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

I need to get the correct map with all the info and places that its containing.

All the examples I find are for getting a blank map, or adding stuff to it.

Thanks,
/b

Comment: What do you mean by a "blank" map?  [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3d7u0nhn/) shows the map I see with your code, it is not "blank", it shows me Sydney Australia. What do you mean by "all the info that its containing"?

Comment: Please include your HTML and CSS so we can check it and make sure you have all the required elements etc... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your supplied JavaScript works for me. Have you included the required div in your webpage?

```
<div id="map-canvas"/>
```

Plus the div may need to be styled, as the map may be there but with 0px height and 0px width (hence making it impossible to see),  the following CSS will make your div fullscreen:

```
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#map-canvas { height: 100% }
```

So, overall, you should have this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
  </body>
</html>
```